Flutter : "Unrecognized feature: 'payment'.", source: https://js.stripe.com/v3
I am using flutter_stripe:lates,
everything working fine but after adding card and process going on there is an error/issue showing:

I/chromium(10630): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Unrecognized feature:
'payment'.", source: https://js.stripe.com/v3 (1) E/chromium(10630):
[ERROR:aw_browser_terminator.cc(166)] Renderer process (10913) crash
detected (code -1).

Is there any solution for this. I think for this error, payment not complete.
Note: Backend working fine and no other issue.


Now please give me the solution for this if anybody faced such issue and solved this.
